# Is there supposed to be an article?

Tags: articles

> "Prime Minister Tony Abbott is preparing to make his second visit to
>   Indonesia in just one week. He’ll head to Bali on Sunday to join 20
>   other leaders for the APEC summit. ***A*** Push for a high trade effect will
>   be high on the agenda." [(extract)](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/406) [(Original audio and script)](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-10-04/news-in-90-seconds/4998206)

I don’t hear the ***a***, so I’m wondering if it is all right without the article in the sentence. Is it okay or not? What is the cause of the reply?

Comment: I hear a /ə/.​​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, what you are hearing is a combination of the presenter's accent and the fact that she is speaking fast. She says "A push" in an Australian accent, yielding:

> /ɛ/ + /pʊʃ/ = /ɛpʊʃ/

which has been elided to

> /pʊʃ/

So in answer to your question, the answer is *no*. The article hasn't been *omitted*, it's just become inaudible because the presenter is Australian and speaking quickly. When writing such a sentence, or indeed when pronouncing it yourself you must include the article, as it is  not optional.